# Encountered two children with the same key - index doesn't work

Tags: react-native

Please help? what wrong here?
i add index but still have warning

```
{options.map((value, index ) => (
      <SelectPicker.Item  key={index} label={value} value={value} />
 ))}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's bad practice to use `index` as keys. You can choose any of the below options to avoid `indexes` or `Math.random()` for providing keys to react or react native components.

**Option 1**

Create static ids yourself of the frontend for a list before using the list to render UI elements.

Create a new array like below:

```
const optionsWithIds = options.map((item, index) => { ...item, id: index });
```

Then, use it like so:

```
{optionsWithIds.map((item, index ) => (
      <SelectPicker.Item  key={item.id} label={item.value} value={item.value} />
 ))}
```

**Option 2**

If your values are unique, which should be the case. Just assign the value as a key. Keys should always be of type string. In case, value is not of type `string`, you should convert it to string using `.toString()`, but also add a check to see if the value exists, else you'll receive an error trying to convert null or undefined to type string, the app will crash.

```
{options.map((value, index ) => (
      <SelectPicker.Item  key={value} label={value} value={value} />
 ))}
```

**Option 3**

Create your own Key generator function.

```
let key = 0 // Make sure this variable is declared globally.

const getKey = () => {
  key += 1
  return key.toString()
}

export default getKey
```

Usage:

```
import getKey from './getKey

{options.map((value, index ) => (
      <SelectPicker.Item  key={getKey()} label={value} value={value} />
 ))}
```

**Option 4**
Use the below options only if the above ones can't be used for some reason.

Add this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) called `nanoid` to your project
and use it instead of index to generate a unique random key. But, use nanoid only in cases where you don't have access to a static unique key element. If you have for eg: an id you receive from the backend, always try to use that. Because the id will remain static (the same) even after a re-render, which is the whole point of using keys in the first place.

Usage:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
// Your other code
<SelectPicker.Item  key={nanoid()} label={value} value={value} />
```

**Option 5**

You can also use this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) called `uuid` to achieve the same results as option 3.

Usage:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

{options.map((value, index ) => (
      <SelectPicker.Item  key={uuidv4()} label={value} value={value} />
 ))}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this not working in iOS, have some another solution?
in iOS this Error: React Native does not have a built-in secure random generator. If you don’t need unpredictable IDs use `nanoid/non-secure`. For secure IDs, import `react-native-get-random-values` before Nano ID.

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer and shared multiple options.